# База данных для плагина wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Задание такое:
Разработать плагин для CMS WordPress, позволяющий реализовать на сайте обработку заявок на получение услуг хостинга и регистрации доменов.
Информация об услугах должна храниться в базе и быть доступной для редактирования с использованием раздела администрирования (с возможностью добавления услугу, удаления услуг).

Возник вопрос по поводу хранения информации услуг в базе. В какой базе данных они должны храниться и где найти ее(эту базу). Сталкиваюсь с этим впервые

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress при установке сразу создает ряд базовых таблиц

```
    #__options
    #__users,
    #__usermeta
    #__posts
    #__postmeta
    #__terms
    #__term_relationships
    #__term_taxonomy
    #__comments
    #__commentmeta
    #__links
```

https://wp-staging.com/docs/the-wordpress-database-structure/

Обычно для собственных плагинов создается собственный post_type https://wp-kama.ru/function/register_post_type

Основные таблицы для хранения данных post_type - #__posts, #__postmeta

Если этих таблиц не достаточно, то есть возможность создавать собственные таблицы

https://deliciousbrains.com/creating-custom-table-php-wordpress/